# Secure Transport: Load server certificate from file

Tags: c++, macos, ssl, keychain

I have some C++ code that uses the [Apple Secure Transport](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/secureTransportRef/Reference/reference.html) and [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) APIs to create an SSL/TLS server (CLI).
The code is already able to load the server cert by a user-provided finger-print from the existing keychain.

However, for compatibility reasons, I'd like to enable the server to also load a cert + key (PEM) from a user-provided set of files.

To be clear: I do not want to import the file into the user's keychain, but instead just use it in that "session".

Basically, fill in the XXX:

```
bool AppleTLSContext::addCredentialFile(const std::string& certfile,
                                        const std::string& keyfile)
{
  if (tryAsFingerprint(certfile)) {
    return true;
  }

  // XXX
}
```

It seems one can use `SecItemImport` and/or `SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent` to import the cert/key into a throw-away keychain with a random password.

- Is there a viable way without using a throw-away keychain?
- If not, is the "throw-away keychain" option a viable solution?
- Also, is it possible to create the throw-away keychain in-memory only? (It seems `SecKeychainCreate` does require a path)

I'm looking for a solution that will run at least on OSX 10.6+ once compiled (`#ifdef`s are OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both files can be clubbed and converted into pkcs 12 format then SecPKCS12Import method can be used.

But SecPKCS12Import does not work properly in root context. I do not know reason of this misbehaviour.

```
OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inPKCS12Data,
                             SecIdentityRef *outIdentity,
                             SecTrustRef *outTrust,
                             CFStringRef keyPassword)
{

OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;
const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
const void *values[] = { keyPassword };
CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = NULL;

optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(
                                       NULL, keys,
                                       values, (keyPassword ? 1 : 0),
                                       NULL, NULL);
CFArrayRef items = NULL;
securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data,
                                optionsDictionary,
                                &items);

if (securityError == 0)
{ 
    CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = (CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (items, 0);

    const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
    tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust,
                                         kSecImportItemIdentity);
    CFRetain(tempIdentity);
    *outIdentity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
    const void *tempTrust = NULL;
    tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
    CFRetain(tempTrust);
    *outTrust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
}
if (optionsDictionary) 
    CFRelease(optionsDictionary);
if (items)
    CFRelease(items);
return securityError;
}
```

Anand

Comment: What do you mean by "But SecPKCS12Import does not work properly in root context"?